# How to use awk command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, awk

I have to write a python script to find available space in /var/tmp folder in linux. So I am using awk command to filter out only available space.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("$(awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' file1.txt)")
```

The output should be 4.7G but it comes 
/bin/sh: 1: 4.7G: not found
and the return value is 127 and not 0.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we do not accept screenshots of code, output and data. Please edit your question and add the outout as code-formatted text.

Comment: Why would you do this? Python is perfectly capable of opening files and string processing. Write a function.

Comment: Please copy&paste the output **as text** instead of showing a screenshot. The code in the image and the code shown as text in the question should match.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that `python` should be sufficient to do what `awk` does here, what you are doing with

```
$(awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' file1.txt)
```

is to run the `awk` command and expand its output as part of the command line by `$(...)`. As this is the only part of the command line, the shell tries to execute `awk`'s output as a command.

If you **really** want to run `awk` from your `python` script, remove `$(` and `)` from your command.

Comment: Thanks Bodo. It was really helpful. I am new to python scripting as well as linux. I was trying to figure out to store the output of  awk command in a variable but it stores the return value.